# Is an SSH connection timeout expected when iptables is set to REJECT?

Tags: ssh, iptables, timeout

We’re setting up a firewall for a machine that should allow:

- incoming SSH connections from particular IP addresses;
- ICMP, except for redirect.

We’ve opted to use REJECT over DROP, at least until we’ve finished our current testing.

```
*filter

# Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and reject traffic to localhost that does not originate from lo0.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Reject ICMP redirect.
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 5 -j REJECT

# Allow ICMP (the types which are not rejected).
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH connections from specific address
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT

# Allow inbound traffic from established connections, including ICMP error returns.
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Log what was incoming but denied (optional but useful).
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound.
-A INPUT -j REJECT

# Log any traffic which was sent to you for forwarding (optional but useful).
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all traffic forwarding.
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

The machine is behind a NAT router, and port 22 is forwarded to it.

When attempting to connect from an unauthorised IP address, the connection to the host times out after a minute or so.

```
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
```

Is this expected? I was thinking the REJECT would result in fairly immediate connection failure. Could it be because the REJECT ICMP packet does not make it back to the connecting machine?

Comment: Or the SSH packet doesn't get there in the first place.  Have you tried SSH without the firewall blocking it to make sure NAT and the SSH server is working?

Comment: Yes, when the connecting machine's IP address is allowed, the SSH connection is successfully established.

Comment: You should try tcpdump on your SSH server to see whether a packet arrives through the firewall, and whether an ICMP message is sent back to the firewall.

Comment: You could try `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset` to check if it's ICMP packet's fault.